# Why doesn't the equipartion theorem apply for a gas of diatomic molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics

The equipartition theorem states that the kinetic energy in a gas of diatomic molecules is equally distributed over all degrees of freedom. So why is the rotation around the molecular axis ruled out (frozen)?

Comment: Ok, before I try an answer,  what's wrong with this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210950/degrees-of-freedom-in-a-diatomic-molecule?rq=1 and this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168943/in-counting-degrees-of-freedom-of-a-linear-molecule-why-is-rotation-about-the-a

Comment: And have you noted the way distinguishable **atoms** $CO$ and indistinguishable atoms $N_2$ are treated in diatomic molecules?

Comment: @Countto10-Hi there again! So only for very high-temperature-gases, the high energy rotation is excited, in which case the equipartition theorem dóes apply? Off course, if the molecules haven't been broken up by the high temperature.If not then the frozen rotation is caused by an equally probable distribution of the velocities of two other molecules as any other distribution. Each of the other two molecules must overlap with one of the atoms in the target molecule and convey one quantum of angular momentum about the molecular bond axis. Correct me if I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: @Countto10-So only if the temperature gets high enough (and the bonds don't break), the equipartition theorem applies. I read the energy levels differ 100 000 times as much per step as in the case of the other rotations. But the other rotations possess a great value of n (the number of angular momentum quanta) if the gas temperature is high, so it remains to been seen if the temperature can be high enough without breaking the bonds. If the energy of the normal rotations is high enough, they can convey a quantum of ("frozen") angular momentum to each of the atoms of the target molecule. :-)

Comment: Whoa!!! What I intended to do was write an answer  so I can learn more about it. I wanted to compare it to the answers already here. It would be purely based around the QM reasons as to why diatomic molecules lose a degree of freedom. My main interest is QFT but I want to get a break from that and get a **general** idea of TD concepts, so my answer would be basic compared to your comments above :). But it might take a  few days as I am only learning it now. But I will take into account your comments above and see if can I answer them. (0r even understand them ;).