# Degree of freedom of diatomic molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

Is there any justification for degree of freedom of diatomic molecules to be two? I believe that degree of freedom are the number of coordinates needed to specify the position of a molecule so how this value is same for diatomic as well as tri atomic linear gas molecules

Comment: Do you mean rotational degrees of freedom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In counting degrees of freedom of a linear molecule, why is rotation about the axis not counted?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168943/)
Also read [Degrees of freedom in a diatomic molecule](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210950/)